# Summing value in a row of dataframe - execution time

Tags: r, dataframe

So i have 2 data frames, both of them have the same structure:

```
V1  V2  V3  V4  C
0   1   1   0  -1
0   0   1   0  -1
2   0   0   0   1
2   0   0   0   1
1   0   0   0   1
2   0   0   0   1
```

The V1-V4 columns are integer type, the C column is factor with 2 levels.
The data frames have different sizes, the first one has ~50 000 rows, the other one has ~600 000 rows. I wrote simple function that divides each element of the row by sum of elements in this row:

```
SimpleFunction <- function(dataset) {
  progress.bar <- create_progress_bar("text")
  progress.bar$init(nrow(dataset))
  for (i in 1:nrow(dataset)) {
    row.sum <- sum(dataset[i,1:4])
    dataset[i,1] <- dataset[i,1] / row.sum
    dataset[i,2] <- dataset[i,2] / row.sum
    dataset[i,3] <- dataset[i,3] / row.sum
    dataset[i,4] <- dataset[i,4] / row.sum
  progress.bar$step()
  } 
  return(dataset)
}
```

Now I tested the times of this function execution with "system.time", and for the 50000 rows data frame it was ~45 sec, but for the 600000 rows data frame it was taking extremely long (around 2 minutes for 1%, I measure it with this simple progress bar from "plyr" package). Now my question is: why? The only thing that has changed is number of rows, the structure of data frame is identical. Shouldn't it be linear growth, like 50000 - 45 sec, 600000 - 540 sec?
I can simply divide the large data frame, run the function on each fragment and then merge them back together, but I really do not understand why is this happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a loop for this R specialises in vectorized computations. All looping through rows does is increase processing time. As such you can do this and R will create a row sum for each row:

```
row.sum <- rowSums(dataset[,1:4])
dataset[,1] <- dataset[,1] / row.sum
dataset[,2] <- dataset[,2] / row.sum
dataset[,3] <- dataset[,3] / row.sum
dataset[,4] <- dataset[,4] / row.sum
```

Comment: row.sum <- sum(dataset[,1:4])  doesn't return vector of sums of elements from each row - it returns sum of all elements in columns 1:4, which is scalar.

Comment: Yes sorry you need to use `rowSums(dataset[,1:4])` . You definitely don't need to use a loop.

Comment: it works with row.sum <- rowSums(dataset[,1:4]) tho, and solves my problem - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`sweep` is useful here if you want one line solution:

```
> dataset[, 1:4] <- sweep(dataset[,-5], 1, rowSums(dataset[,-5]), FUN="/")
> dataset
  V1  V2  V3 V4  C
1  0 0.5 0.5  0 -1
2  0 0.0 1.0  0 -1
3  1 0.0 0.0  0  1
4  1 0.0 0.0  0  1
5  1 0.0 0.0  0  1
6  1 0.0 0.0  0  1
```

`apply` is also suitable:

```
dataset[, -5] <- apply(dataset[,-5], 2, function(x) x/rowSums(dataset[,-5]))
```